# Is there a way to deploy CSS without committing it to a git repo?

Tags: git, css, sass

I'm working on a project and need to push my Sass files to a repo but also deploy the compiled CSS to the server **without committing them to my repo.** I'm using Git-Ftp to push my updates.

Is anyone aware of a concise method of achieving this?

Comment: The simplest would be to FTP the compiled css manually with an FTP program, like FileZilla. It looks like Git-Ftp wouldn't know about the files unless you committed them. Also: what's the downside of committing them? Then everything would deploy the same way, which seems easier.

Comment: Why don't you compile the Sass on the server?

Comment: @rednaw How would I go about compiling Sass on the server?

Comment: Well, just the same way you do it anywhere, execute `sass input.scss output.css`, see the [documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#using_sass)

Answer (score 0):

You could use an intermediate local repo to which:

- you would push your Sass files
- you would add/update your compiled css file (taking them from your first repo)
- push everything

You can add files from outside your second clone

```
cd /path/second/cloned/repo
git add --work-tree=/path/first/repo -- yourCompiledCssFiles
```

Your original repo doesn't have those css files versioned.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not familiar with the `--work-tree` option. Do you know where I can find it in Git's documentation?